# How do I increase the background size?

Tags: javascript

How do i make the black box reach the full height?

[trulyamped.com/dropit](http://trulyamped.com/dropit)

When you click on dropdown I want the entire background to be black. I Tried to do height:100% with position:abosulute but it does not seem to work. Please let me know how to get around this. Also an added bonus if you would like to help with it too is creating a animation so that the items on the nav appear with a small delay and fade-in.
Thanks

I want it to look similar to the MENU/Navigation on [www.domanistudios.com/mobile/](http://www.domanistudios.com/mobile/)

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to find the height of the browser window and then you can apply this height to the ul element. A simple example for this

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8hKEd/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#clickme').click(function(){
                $('#showme').css({'height' : $(window).height()});
                $('#showme').slideToggle('slow');


            });

        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="clickme" href="#">Click Me</a>

<ul id="showme" style="display:none; background-color: #000; color: #fff;">
    <li>
        Some Text
    </li>
    <li>
        Some Text
    </li>
    <li>
        Some Text
    </li>
    <li>
        Some Text
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect. this ended up working for me thanks.  But if i resize the window the background does not match, is there any way to have it refresh or constantly adjust to the active height?>

Comment: The reason why the background image is not resizing correctly is because the window height is being added to the ul but there is already some space being used by the anchor tag on the top of the page. What you can do is reduce the height being applied to the ul by say 65px and that should cover the difference in height caused due to the anchor tag. Try changing

$('#showme').css({'height' : $(window).height()});

to

$('#showme').css({'height' : $(window).height()-65});

Comment: http://trulyamped.com/dropit/  take a look there. The height fits perfectly but once you resize the window the height is no longer fitting the site perfectly. Do you see what I am talking about>?

Comment: To fix that you need to calculate the new window height after every re-size and then apply this new height to your ul. Add this to your document ready function:

$( window ).resize(function() {
                $('#showme').css({'height' : $(window).height()-65});
              });

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the height of the `ul` rather than the height of `body`. `body` has height based on the elements in it. Increase the height of `ul menu` class to `1000px`. That should give you what you need.

```
.menu ul {
    display: none;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I would like the height to be 100% though. I want it to adjust to the size of the persons browser dimensions. Any idea how.